# CSS Dropdown-menu not displaying when <li>-element is hovered.

Tags: html, css

I have a top navigation bar with 4 options, where I wish that while the fourth option is hovered, a dropdown-menu will display.

The navigation bar is an unordered list, and the dropdown-menu (which should be activated by the fourth option) is a div consisting of 3 links.

The list item that is supposed to display the dropdown-menu while hovered:

```
    <li class="dropdownbutton"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

With the help of this line of code:

```
    .dropdownbutton:hover .dropdowncontent {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And this is the CSS for the dropdown-content:

```
    .dropdowncontent {
    display:none;
    background-color:#333;
    margin-left:272px;
    width:90px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide a demo via code snippet, on Plunker or JSfiddle? It's hard figure out the problem from this little code

Comment: just to see if this is a CSS proximity issue, what happens when you change it to `display:inline-block !important;` ?

Comment: Here, I provided a JSfiddle :) https://jsfiddle.net/8ykuuj0v/1/

Comment: @phirschybar There is no difference when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

This should be allright.

```css
ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 background-color: #333;
}
ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #333;
}
ul li a {
 display: block;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 16px 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-family: Arial;
}
ul li a:hover {
 background-color: #555;
}
ul li ul.dropdown {
 min-width: 100%;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 999;
 left: 0;
 width: 90px;
}
ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
 display: block;
}
ul li ul.dropdown li {
 display: block;
}
ul li ul.dropdown li a {
 font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
 <ul class="dropdown">
 <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```